# How can I select a "last-child of a last-child"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the last element contained in the last col-xs-12 div with CSS. The thing is that the element is dynamic, so it can be an h2 or h3 etc.

```
<div class="banner-text-img">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">
       <p>...</p>
       <h1>...</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I achieved that by selecting tag by tag, but that's not probably the perfect choice.

```
.banner-text-img div[class^="col"]:last-child h1, .banner-text-img div[class^="col"]:last-child h2... etc.
```

Comment: Does `.row > :last-child > :last-child` not work?

Comment: Are there any other columns then `col-cs-12` present in that `row? Especially after the last `col-cs-12`?

Comment: @hsan it works as well thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the asterisk *

```
 .banner-text-img div[class^="col"]:last-child *:last-child
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the asterisk `*` to select any element and use `:last-child` to target the last element.

`.col-xs-12 > *:last-child`

https://codepen.io/paulbremer/pen/JxEwbx

Comment: your selector does not select the last `.col-xs-12` like requested... _"contained in the last col-xs-12"_